# Sort a Java collection object based on one field in it and apply checks

Tags: java, list, java-8, null-check

```
retList.sort((comp1, comp2) ->
         compartmentOrderMap.get(comp2.getCompartment()).compareTo(compartmentOrderMap
        .get(comp1.getCompartment())));
```

I want to add a null check before comparing. How can I do that?

```
retList.sort((comp1, comp2) ->
            if(compartmentOrderMap.get(comp2.getCompartment()) != null && compartmentOrderMap.get(comp1.getCompartment()) != null)
                compartmentOrderMap.get(comp2.getCompartment()).compareTo(compartmentOrderMap
                .get(comp1.getCompartment()));
        );

//I want to do something like this
```

Comment: Should the null check just skip the element or should it stop the sorting? What do you want to null-check, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put {} inside the lambda for multiple line code:

```
retList.sort((comp1, comp2) -> {
            if(compartmentOrderMap.get(comp2.getCompartment()) != null && compartmentOrderMap.get(comp1.getCompartment()) != null)
                return compartmentOrderMap.get(comp2.getCompartment()).compareTo(compartmentOrderMap
                .get(comp1.getCompartment()));
            else 
               // throw a RuntimeException or return some integer value based on your logic
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Your operation

```java
retList.sort((comp1, comp2) ->
    compartmentOrderMap.get(comp2.getCompartment())
        .compareTo(compartmentOrderMap.get(comp1.getCompartment())));
```

is equivalent to

```java
retList.sort(Comparator.comparing(
    c -> compartmentOrderMap.get(c.getCompartment()), 
    Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

With this factory based form, you can easily replace the value comparator with a null safe variant, e.g.

```java
retList.sort(Comparator.comparing(
    c -> compartmentOrderMap.get(c.getCompartment()),
    Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
```

You have to decide for a policy. Instead of `nullsFirst` you can also use `nullsLast`.

Answer (score 1):

Use if/then/else to specify your needs. If you want all of this within one line, check the ternary operator on
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

It is explained including some examples here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Ternary-Operator-Examples